# Using spring cloud feign causes java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/Logger

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-feign

I enabled my spring cloud for feignClients like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@RestController
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableFeignClients

public class SpringCloudConfigClientApplication {
}
```

But as oon as I add enableFeignClients, I got this error during compilation,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: feign/Logger
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2688)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1962)
```

My POM is

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.SpringCloudConfigClientApplication</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-hystrix</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

In order to resolve feign logger issue, what other dependency do I need to add to the POM?

Thanks

Thank you @spencergibb, based on your suggestion, it worked after I change my pom. Now I have another issue for using FeignClient. Please see below:

```
@Autowired
    StoreClient storeClient;
    @RequestMapping("/stores")
    public List<Store> stores() {
        return storeClient.getStores();
    }
```

and interface is:

```
@FeignClient("store")
public interface StoreClient {
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/stores")
    List<Store> getStores();
}
```

The store entity is:

```
public class Store {

    private long id;
    private String name;
    private String zip;

    public Store(long id, String name, String zip) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.zip = zip;
    }
}
```

Now when I retrieve in URL, I got this error,

```
ue Jun 09 15:30:10 PDT 2015
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Could not read JSON: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class demo.entity.Store]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7db6c3dc; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0]); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class demo.entity.Store]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@7db6c3dc; line: 1, column: 3] (through reference chain: java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

**Seemed the error here is retrieved list can not be converted to store class.** 
So in order to use FeignClient, any other mapper we need to include to convert JSON into objects?

Thanks

Comment: Answer myself, having to put a default empty constructor in the entity classs in order to make the mapper working. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You are missing `spring-cloud-starter-feign`

Comment: Thank you, @spencergibb, you are right. Can you help to tell how to map from JSON into objects? It seemed FeignClient is not doing this.

Comment: Does your object have a public no-arg constructor?